# Trying to create a html form, button won't compute answer?

Tags: html

so I have the code and my professor said it was all correct--however, once I run the code the "compute" button won't display the answer where it should. Can I have extra eyes to see where I'm going wrong?

```js
function compute() {
  myHours = parseFloat(document.getElementById("hours").value);
  if (document.getElementById("packageA").checked)

  {
    if (myHours > 10) {
      totalAmount = 9.95 + ((myHours - 10) * 2);
    } else {
      totalAmount = 9.95;
    }

  } else if (document.getElementById("packageB").checked) {
    if (myHours > 20) {
      totalAmount = 14.95 + ((myHours - 20) * 1);
    } else {
      totalAmount = 14.95;
    }
  } else {
    totalAmount = 19.00;
  }

  if (document.getElementById("nonprofit").checked) {
    totalAmount = totalAmount * .8;
  }
  document.getElementById("total").value = totalAmount.toFixed(2);
}
```

```html
<form name="partTwo" action="">
  Enter Hours:
  <input type="text" id="hours" name="Enter Hours" value="" />
  <br>Select Package:
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="package" value=9.95 id="packageA" />Package A: 10 hours of access for $9.95 per month. Additional hours are $2.00 per hour.
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="package" value="14.95" id="packageB" />Package B: 20 hours of access for $14.95 per month. Additional hours are $1.00 per hour.
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="package" value="19.95" id="packageC" />Package C: Unlimited access for $19.95 per month.
  <br>
  <br>Non-Profit Organization
  <input type="checkbox" name="Non-profit organization" value="ON" id="nonprofit" />
  <br>Total Amount
  <input type="text" name="Total Amount" value="" id="total" />
  <br>

  <input type="button" value="Compute" name="btnCompute" onClick="compute()" />
</form>
```

Comment: have you tried to use `console.log` or look at the console if you have any errors? or tried to google how to get the value of a radio button or check if it is checked like that.

Comment: "won't display the answer where it should". So, where _should_ it display the answer? I converted your code to a runnable snippet and to me it looks perfectly ok.

Comment: according to your code the answer appears exactly where it should - in the total textbox. Where should it be?

Comment: y'all are too sassy I swear. I mean it won't show the answer at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily solve it by removing the `onClick="compute()"` from the input and attach an event handler to the button in the script using

```
document.getElementById("compute").addEventListener("click", compute, false);
```

and adding the `id="compute"` to the input. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/376e1aya/).